# Website not resizing to mobile correctly (meta values in place)

Tags: jquery, html, css, xhtml, meta

I'm setting up a basic website, and when I view it on mobile, it opens zoomed in, instead of showing the full width of the mobile CSS (480px).

I have already gone through setting up the meta correctly -

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=0"/>
```

And I have tried doing initial-zoom but that is not working.

The website is: http://scottstuart.co/hopkinsgroupwp/

Does anyone know how this could be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Because the meta tag you are sharing with us says "make the width of the site equal to the width of the device viewport".

Then you CSS says "make this div 480px wide".

The browser has no choice but to put a horizontal scrollbar on your site to accommodate the forced 480px width.

**SOLUTION**, two things...

1) add this to the viewport meta tag value:

```
initial-scale=1
```

2) You should probably go to `width:100%` in another media query when the viewport is less than 480px.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your meta tag. 
Instead of `user-scalable=0` you should write `initial-scale=1.0`.

Besides that, I highly recommend you to use relative length units, such as %,vh and vw, instead of absolute length units, such as px. That would make it easier for the content to look the same way in different devices.